# bash if statement: Expression Syntax

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I get this error `if: Expression Syntax.`

on this script

```
#!/bin/sh

pmon_num=`ps -ef | grep pmon | wc -l`
echo $pmon_num
if [ $pmon_num -gt 1 ]
then

#code

fi
```

If I run the script like this: `/tmp/script.sh` - it works. But the error comes from crontab. Crontab line is like that:

```
* * * * * /tmp/script.sh   > /tmp/log.log 2>&1 &
```

`ls -l` on `/tmp/script.sh`:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 oracle dba 705 Dec 12 07:10 /tmp/script.sh
```

Cant understand the problem.

EDIT:

I also tried to change the if statement to:

```
if [ 1 -gt 1 ]
```

And I still got the error.

Comment: better to change your interpreter. You might using old "sh". maybe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if [ $pmon_num -gt 1 ]
then

fi
```

With:

```
if ( $pmon_num > 1 ) then
endif
```

Comment: If this worked for you, it means your question is wrong, or your environment is highly unusual.  In `sh` this would create a subshell and attempt to run the contents of the variable as a statement, with standard output redirected to a file named `1`.  I am downvoting this as unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I suspect you were using `tcsh`, not `sh`.  These are completely different shells, with different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a Bash error message. So, cron is apparently invoking a different shell (maybe csh?). To fix that, and ensure that this is running with an appropriate interpreter, change this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: didnt help, I believe the system default is `tcsh` but `#!/bin/tcsh` also didnt help.

Comment: @nir: Define "didnt help". Did it at least give a better/different error-message?

Comment: @nir It wouldn't help as the script needs to contain valid `csh` syntax; the problem is that you're using `sh` (or `bash`) syntax and executing that script using `csh` or `tcsh`.

Comment: change the crontab to '/bin/sh /tmp/script.sh' would be an interesting test too. Is sh a link to csh or tcsh? or perhaps somewhere in crontab it changes the shell.

Comment: You should prefer `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts executed inside cron doesn't have PATH nor do they source system wide or user profile. The script didn't find the commands ps, grep and wc thus $pmon_num is empty.

Either set the PATH in the script or fully qualify the pathnames of the commands.

On a side note, why use grep and pipe to wc -l? You can just use grep -c since you are not expecting several pmons in one line and it will return the count.

EDIT:

Adding modified code for you.

```
#!/bin/sh

pmon_num=`/bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep -c pmon`
echo $pmon_num
if [ $pmon_num -gt 1 ]
then

#code

fi
```

EDIT:

Here's how you can test what your cron thinks of PATH and unqualified commands.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $PATH > /tmp/cronjob.out
which ps >> /tmp/cronjob.out 2>&1
which grep >> /tmp/cronjob.out 2>&1
which wc >> /tmp/cronjob.out 2>&1
```

After cron has executed this script check the content of /tmp/cronjob.out.

Comment: Are you sure the cron-job wouldn't find `wc`? In my experience cron-jobs do usually seem to start out with a rudimentary path, which I think would find `wc`. (But +1: the explanation does make sense, if it's correct. If the shell were Bash, a missing `wc` would result in a more-useful error-message, but as I noted in my answer, this script is apparently not being run in Bash.)

Comment: see my edit in the question

Comment: Back ticks only assigns the stdout to pmon_num. Any errors are sent to stderr and in this case stderr is not redirected to stdout usually by using 2>&1. Errors are either thrown out or mailed to the owner of the cronjob. The stdout is left empty.

Comment: you may want to use if [[ $pmon_num -gt 1 ]]

Answer (score 0):

Since it's working in your current enviroment, try fixing your SHELL, PATH variables, and interpreter and see if you still get the error. e.g. run

```
printf "SHELL=$SHELL\nPATH=$PATH\n* * * * * /bin/sh /tmp/script.sh   > /tmp/log.log 2>&1 &\n"
```

That will give you some output like

```
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/bin:etc...
* * * * * /bin/sh /tmp/script.sh   > /tmp/log.log 2>&1 &
```

But containing your SHELL and PATH. Then edit whichever crontab again with `crontab -e` and replace it with above input and see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that `sh != bash`! If you want bash then tell it that! `#!/usr/bin/env bash`!